# searching all fields in a table in django

Tags: python, django

How to search all fields in a table in django using filter clause 
ex:table.object.filter(any field in the table="sumthing")

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I agree with Alasdair, but the answer to your question is this though:

```
from django.db.models import CharField
from django.db.models import  Q

fields = [f for f in table._meta.fields if isinstance(f, CharField)]
queries = [Q(**{f.name: SEARCH_TERM}) for f in fields]

qs = Q()
for query in queries:
    qs = qs | query

table.objects.filter(qs)
```

note: I have not tested this code, but it should get you quite a bit close to your goal

Comment: that's great! thank you.
I'm trying to have this working with a "LIKE" sql comparison, is there a way to do that ?

Comment: if someone want to use filter like a "LIKE", modify this [Q(**{f.name: SEARCH_TERM}) for f in fields] to this [Q(**{f.name + "__icontains": SEARCH_TERM}) for f in fields]
<field_name> + "__icontains" = <pattern> is just SQL "<field_name> LIKE <pattern>".

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the filter clause is suited to this kind of search. You might want to check out [Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/).

Comment: +1, it sure looks like a job for a full text search mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Just noticed this is limited to Postgres

Ancient question, but for further reference:

Apparently in django 1.10 [SearchVector](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchvector) class was added.

Usage from the docs:

> Searching against a single field is great but rather limiting. The Entry instances we’re searching belong to a Blog, which has a tagline field. To query against both fields, use a SearchVector:

```
>>> from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector
>>> Entry.objects.annotate(
...     search=SearchVector('body_text', 'blog__tagline'),
... ).filter(search='Cheese')
[<Entry: Cheese on Toast recipes>, <Entry: Pizza Recipes>]
```