# How to use Django/Rest Framework to search a database table without specifying a column?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**Initial question:**

Following the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters), to get a QuerySet of blog entries from the year 2006, we can use filter() like so:

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2006)
```

Retrieving specific objects with filter, it is assumed that we know which column to search in.
How can we search for an object if we do not know which column it could be in?

For a small number of columns, we could chain the filters like so:

```
Entry.objects.filter(column1='foo').filter(column2='foo')
```

With +30 columns, this seems highly repetitive. What is a better way of doing this?

**A follow up question:**

Given that in **urlpatterns** we find the following path:

```
path('foo/bar/<str:object>/', views.ViewObject.as_view())
```

And **ViewObject** uses the Rest Framework generic views:

```
class ViewObject(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = ObjectSerializer
    ...
    queryset = ?
```

How can we construct the ViewObject view such that parameter `<str:object>` is used to search for a value in all columns of a database table?

Comment: I assume [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866847/searching-all-fields-in-a-table-in-django) helps you. Maybe you have to override `retrieve()` or `get_queryset()`

Comment: I reviewed the answer. Absolutely correct @KlimBim :+1

Answer (score 0):

For the first question as far as I understand you would like to create a searchbar or something similiar to that so it looks like what you are looking for is full text search in django. Example usage:

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector
>>> Entry.objects.annotate(
...     search=SearchVector('field_one', 'field_two'),
... ).filter(search='string')
```

`SearchVector` takes fields as args that will be looked in, and `filter(search='string')` actual string to look up and this will return a queryset.
You can create better queries and order results with `SearchQuery` and `SearchRank`.
[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) is the documentation.

For the second question there is a 3rd party package called `django-filter`. DRF documentation mentions it in filter api tutorial but you can check out documentation from [here](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems that full text search only applies to PostgreSQL. Are there other solutions possible for SQLite? If not, I will just switch the DB to Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

I could have commented but am not allowed. You can try the following link [pass all fields of model in django filter backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542224/pass-all-fields-of-model-in-django-filter-backend)

```
class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = [f.name for f in User._meta.get_fields()]
```